# Error adding a new field to 1 model in Django 1.7

Tags: django

I am trying to add a new field to a model - normally a simple process. On one model, I get an error (adding the same field to a different model in the same app causes no problems at all).

The field:

```
mediumlink = models.URLField(max_length=500, null=True)
```

Although, any field type or name has the same error.

The error, when using makemigrations:

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column images_locationimage.mediumlink does not exist
LINE 1: ...."imagelink", "images_locationimage"."thumblink", "images_lo...
                                                             ^
```

I'm stumped! Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Your migrations are behind on that particular model. Run migrate first.

Comment: No luck - tried migrate, nothing to migrate - same error afterwards trying to makemigrations

Comment: You may have added some code to a view or somewhere in your model that accesses this and it needs the migration you are trying to apply before it can exist. Comment code like that in your main files out, re-run the migration, uncomment.

Comment: excellent - that was exactly it. I found the last referenced line of code in terminal, commented it out and everything worked. Thanks! (if you want to answer the question, I'll mark your answer correct).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are certain files that Django has to have in a working state before it can do other things -- particularly, I think, where models and views are defined (not sure exactly and the list is much shorter with Django 1.7). In any case, if you reference your change before the migration is made and applied, you can find yourself in a catch-22 of needing the migration before you can make the migration. Always get your database in order first before you start using your changes. (In your case, commenting out the offending code will let you proceed with the migration, then quickly get back to where you were.)