# Add A New Field To Existing Model - django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column {field} does not exist

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models, database-migration

**models.py**

I have a `Scorecard` model that has a ManyToManyField to another model named `Account`:

```
class Scorecard(models.Model):

    ....
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    accounts = models.ManyToManyField(Account)
    ...

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

My `Account` class currently has four fields (account_name, adwords_account_id, bingads_account_id, label).

```
class Account(models.Model):

    account_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    adwords_account_id = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True)
    bingads_account_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    # gemini_account_id = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True)
    label = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.account_name
```

Notice that field `gemini_account_id` is commented out. **I want to add this field to the model.**

If I leave `gemini_account_id` commented out and runserver, everything works fine.

If I then uncomment `gemini_account_id` and do `python manage.py makemigrations`

```
(venv) C:\Django\scorecard>python manage.py makemigrations
```

FULL ERROR

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: column scorecards_account.gemini_account_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...t_id", "scorecards_account"."bingads_account_id", "scorecard...
                                                             ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 347, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 120, in populate
    app_config.ready()
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\apps.py", line 23, in ready
    self.module.autodiscover()
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\__init__.py", line 26, in autodiscover
    autodiscover_modules('admin', register_to=site)
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\utils\module_loading.py", line 47, in autodiscover_modules
    import_module('%s.%s' % (app_config.name, module_to_search))
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Django\scorecard\scorecards\admin.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scorecards.forms import (ScorecardAdminForm, AccountAdminForm, ReportTypeAdminForm,
  File "C:\Django\scorecard\scorecards\forms.py", line 5, in <module>
    class ScorecardAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):
  File "C:\Django\scorecard\scorecards\forms.py", line 7, in ScorecardAdminForm
    class Meta:
  File "C:\Django\scorecard\scorecards\forms.py", line 15, in Meta
    attrs={'class': 'wide-select'}),
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\forms\widgets.py", line 558, in __init__
    self.choices = list(choices)
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 272, in __iter__
    self._fetch_all()
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 1179, in _fetch_all
    self._result_cache = list(self._iterable_class(self))
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py", line 54, in __iter__
    results = compiler.execute_sql(chunked_fetch=self.chunked_fetch, chunk_size=self.chunk_size)
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\compiler.py", line 1063, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 100, in execute
    return super().execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 68, in execute
    return self._execute_with_wrappers(sql, params, many=False, executor=self._execute)
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 77, in _execute_with_wrappers
    return executor(sql, params, many, context)
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 89, in __exit__
    raise dj_exc_value.with_traceback(traceback) from exc_value
  File "C:\Django\venv\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\utils.py", line 85, in _execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: column scorecards_account.gemini_account_id does not exist
LINE 1: ...t_id", "scorecards_account"."bingads_account_id", "scorecard...
                                                             ^
```

Okay. So this is telling me that the `gemini_account_id` column does not exist in the database. My reaction to that is "that's because I'm tryING TO ADD IT!". I thought `makemigrations` helps me do this?

**What is the appropriate course of action steps to add a new field to an existing model (`Account`) that is a "ManyToManyField" of another model (`Scorecard`)?**

[image: Picture of PostGreSQL Table]

My database is PostgrSQL.

What have I tried:

1. `python manage.py makemigrations scorecards` : same error as above
2. renamed the migrations folder, created empty one with **init**.py: same error as above.
3. I went through each previous migration, deleted one at a time and ran makemigrations: same error as above every time

Other posts I've looked at:

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28821060/error-adding-a-new-field-to-1-model-in-django-1-7) seems like the closest but the advice is that "migrations are behind on that particular model".

**UPDATE:**
Here is the **forms.py ScorecardAdminForm**:

```
class ScorecardAdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:

        model = Scorecard
        fields = '__all__'
        #fields = ('name', 'accounts', 'report_type', 'date_range')
        widgets = {
            'name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'wide-select'}),
            'accounts': forms.SelectMultiple(choices=Account.objects.all(),
                                             attrs={'class': 'wide-select'}),
            'report_type': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'wide-select'}),
            'date_range': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'wide-select'}),
            'time_segment': forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'wide-select'})
        }

    def clean(self):
        cleaned_data = super().clean()
        date_range = cleaned_data.get('date_range')
        start_date = cleaned_data.get('start_date')
        end_date = cleaned_data.get('end_date')

        if date_range == 'CUSTOM_DATE':
            if start_date is None or end_date is None:
                raise ValidationError(
                    "Start or end can't be left blank "
                    "when report type is custom date range."
                )
```

I think I did get everything to migrate by commenting out everything in admin.py, and forms.py, then following [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30561845/1577947). **Was the cause in my `ScorecardAdminForm`? Maybe the raise ValidationError part?** Sorry I'm such a lost little lamb.

Comment: That error seems to be happening when importing something in your `admin`? When you run `makemigrations` did you get a migration file (inside `scorecards/migrations/`?)? Did you actually run the migration? (`python manage.py migrate`)?

Comment: Also, do you have something in your `admin.py` or your forms or something that would start spawning queries on import?

Comment: @BorrajaX Turns out, this was good advice. I do have an admin.py that I've customized extensively. When I comment everything out in that file and run makemigrations, it mentions a non-nullable field. I'm still digging in... I'll try your answer below.

Comment: That could be it. If the `non-nullable` is your new `gemini_account_id`, you can try adding `default=""` to the field. Otherwise, `makemigrations` will **demand** a default value to be assigned for the migration (it needs to provide a value for the new column of the already existing entries in the DB). If you don't want to keep that default, you may wanna edit the migration and add some custom python code that assigns the "right" values to the field. [Doc on RunPython](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/migration-operations/#django.db.migrations.operations.RunPython)

Comment: The traceback shows that the problem is something in your ScorecardAdminForm, which seems to be making a database query at definition time. You should show the code for that form.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated the question with `ScorecardAdminForm`. I define a clean function. Could that be it the cause? I never know how much code to post for Django questions. I need to get better at that.

Comment: No, the problem is the queryset in the choices for the report_type widget. That query is being executed when the class is imported. You shouldn't put queries there.

Comment: @DanielRoseman If you want to write an answer, I'll likely accept it (just for anyone who might stumble across this type of question).

Answer (score 0):

The field is referenced via the admin form. Remove the reference from the ScorecardAdminForm and make migrations first.